# Include apsrtable (or stargazer) output in an Rmd file

Tags: windows, r, latex, knitr, r-markdown

I tried to include the summary of an `lm` object in an Rmd file, using code like the following but it didn't work. Could you help me do that?

````
```{r summary_lm, results='asis', echo=FALSE, comment=NA}

library(apsrtable)
my_model <- lm(y ~ x, data = data.frame(y = rnorm(10), x = 1:10))
res <- apsrtable(my_model) # my_model is a linear regression model (lm)

cat("$$latex \n",res,"\n$$ \n")

```
````

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `$$` syntax only applies to math expressions, and you were trying to put a table in it, which will not work. The `apsrtable`, as far as I understand, is for LaTeX only, but LaTeX and Markdown are very different -- there is little hope you can redo LaTeX entirely with Markdown. I think people invented the `$$` syntax for Markdown due to the fact that it is well supported by MathJax, and also note there are many variants/flavors based on the original Markdown.

At the moment you may consider:

- use the `xtable` or `ascii` or `R2HTML` package to generate HTML tables
- request the package author of `apsrtable` to support HTML tables

Answer (score 3):

What about including `my_model` in Markdown format with [`pander˙](http://rapporter.github.com/pander/):

```
> library(pander)
> pander(my_model)

--------------------------------------------------------------
     &nbsp;        Estimate   Std. Error   t value   Pr(>|t|) 
----------------- ---------- ------------ --------- ----------
      **x**         0.1174      0.1573     0.7465     0.4767  

 **(Intercept)**   -0.2889      0.9759     -0.296     0.7748  
--------------------------------------------------------------

Table: Fitting linear model: y ~ x
```

Or in PHP MarkdownExtra/rmarkdown format:

```
> panderOptions('table.style', 'rmarkdown')
> pander(my_model)


|      &nbsp;       |  Estimate  |  Std. Error  |  t value  |  Pr(>|t|)  |
|:-----------------:|:----------:|:------------:|:---------:|:----------:|
|       **x**       |   0.1174   |    0.1573    |  0.7465   |   0.4767   |
|  **(Intercept)**  |  -0.2889   |    0.9759    |  -0.296   |   0.7748   |

Table: Fitting linear model: y ~ x
```

Answer (score 0):

Cross-posting my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51673007/2563804) to [Table of multiple lm() models using apsrtable in Rmarkdown](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44278665/2563804):

It can be done in a `pdf_document` with apsrtable and also stargazer, which additionally supports HTML.

````
---
title: "stargazer"
author: "hplieninger"
date: "3 August 2018"
output: pdf_document
header-includes:
    - \usepackage{dcolumn}
---

```{r}
m1 <- lm(Fertility ~ Education , data = swiss)
m2 <- lm(Fertility ~ Education + Agriculture, data = swiss)
m3 <- lm(Fertility ~ . , data = swiss)
```

```{r, results='asis'}
apsrtable::apsrtable(m1, m2, m3, Sweave = TRUE)
```

```{r, results='asis'}
# If output: pdf_document
stargazer::stargazer(m1, m2, m3)
# If output: html_document
# stargazer::stargazer(m1, m2, m3, type = "html")
```
````